# Removing multiple items from listview

Tags: java, android, xml, listview

I'm tring to remove the selected items from a Listview. I wrote this code.

```
int items;

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    if(requestCode == 1) {
        try {
            for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
                applicationInfo = getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(adapter.getList().get(a), a);
            }
        } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
            items = adapter.getPositions().get(a);
            appInfoArrayList.remove(items);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            mActionMode.finish();
            }
            }

    }
    else {

    }
}
```

This code works BUT there is a problem: remove ONLY the last selected items. For example, if you click the Items 1,2 and 3, with this code only the items number 3 is removed. Why? Teorically the content of "items" variable should not be updated at each cycle of the for?

Answer (score 0):

Use notifydatasetchanged after for

Answer (score 0):

In adapter set remove method and pass int array containing the item position to remove

```
public void remove(int[] items) {
    for(int position : items) {
        // in your case it might be appInfoArrayList.remove(items[position])
        Collection.remove(items[position])
    }
}
```

and then in your activity

```
    int items[] = new int[adapter.getPositions().size()];
    //some code above ...
    catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
            items[a] = adapter.getPositions().get(a);
        }
        adapter.remove(items);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        mActionMode.finish();
    }
```

The idea is to get the positions to be removed and then pass this info to adapter to remove this positions all at once and then you notify adapter to make the changes in view.

i guess you do not require try catch block try this :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    int items[] = new int[adapter.getPositions().size()];
    if(requestCode == 1) {
    for(int a=0; a<adapter.getPositions().size(); a++) {
        items[a] = adapter.getPositions().get(a);
    }
    adapter.remove(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    mActionMode.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error in remove method: Collection cannot be resolved. How can i solve?

Comment: Collection in my code is just an example, it is the List object which you are passing to adapter. collection i meant to say in general any java Collection ie List objects.

ie : List<Class> data; so i meant to say data.remove(); i guess in your case it is "appInfoArrayList"